# How to achieve Dynamic routing in React Router 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a list of articles like this:

```
<div>
   {
       this.props.articles.map(article => {
            return (
                <ArticleCard key={article._id} article={article} />
            )
        })
    }
</div>
```

In the ArticleCard component, I'm only showing the title of my article. I want to put a link to it which would create new URL like 'article-title' and show the content.

How to achieve this?

Comment: if I understand you right, you want each card to have a link such as: `/articles/article-title` which will route to an `Article` component that will render the contents of `article-title`? (where `article-title` is a dynamic string)

Comment: yes, article-title is dynamic string

Comment: and where is this "content"? I'm assuming it's a separate API call using the `article-title` as a query?

Comment: yes, content will be another api call using article._id to render another component.

Comment: Now where is the problem? Have you read the docs at all? Use `<Link to="/article1">Article1</Link>` and `<Route path="/:id" component={articleDetail}/>`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your `ArticleCard`, you have to create a `Link` that will route to your full `Article`. This link will include the `id` of the article you are trying to render (ex. `articles/${article._id}`)

By writing the `Route` path of the component `Article` as `articles/:id`, this will allow us to catch that `id` when `Article` is rendered (accessible via `this.props.match.params.id`)

Then, assuming that `id` is used to fetch the article from some other API, a good place to call that would be the `componentDidMount` of your `Article` component.

Here is a small example which may help you out:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom'

const ParamsExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={ArticleList} />
      <Route path="/articles/:id" component={Article} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
)

const article = {
  _id: 1,
  title: 'First Article'
};

const ArticleList = () => (
  <div>
    <ArticleCard key={article._id} article={article} />
  </div>
);

const ArticleCard = ({ article }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>{article.title}</h2>
    <Link to={`/articles/${article._id}`}>SEE MORE</Link>
  </div>
);

class Article extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('Fetch API here: ', this.props.match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {`Fetching...${this.props.match.params.id}`}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ParamsExample
```